# How to export multiple namespaces together?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

a.ts

```
export namespace NSA {
  export function fnA() {}
}
```

b.ts

```
export namespace NSB {
  export function fnB() {}
}
```

I want to export them together from one file like this,

merged.ts

```
export * from "./a.ts";
export * from "./b.ts";
```

Then refer it in my app like this,

app.component.ts

```
import {NSB} from 'merged';
```

when I try the above it's not able to find NSA{} or NSB{} in merged

Answer (score 0):

> when I try the above it's not able to find NSA{} or NSB{} in merged

It works as expected. Hints why it doesn't for you:

- Restart your IDE
- Test on the terminal
- Make sure your `package.json` has *typings*